# get the post thumbnail returns the full size

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

The function `get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail');` not always returns the thumb size of the image (which is 100x100) for some posts it does but for most of them it doesn't. Even though the actual file exists (say for image `myImg.jpg` there is a thumb image under the name `myImg-100x100.jpg`) but still the function returns the full size.
any thought on troubleshooting this?

Update, I just noticed that the images that are returning the full size are named in Arabic characters, could this cause the issue?

Comment: Do all of your posts have "Feature Image" set?

Comment: Yes all of them have, and the correct one is returned, just not the right size.

Comment: In your settings what are the media sizes defined for thumbnail, medium and large? What size do you want returned?

Comment: "Update, I just noticed that the images that are returning the full size are named in Arabic characters, could this cause the issue?" Definitely yes, special characters in filenames should be avoided at all costs as some internet browsers don't have the logic to read special characters, thus the image is ignored

Comment: So I should tell the site owners to rename their images before uploading them? shouldn't wordpress be taking care of special characters in filenames before uploading them?